# WCF Net.tcp VS SqlServer on net

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, net.tcp

i'm starting a new project, where i'll have a server. 
and i've a doubt about implement using WCF net.tcp, with windows services on the server side, or a sql server direct access from the net.

I'm tempting to use wcf, but i don't know the performance between them.

The system will have a lot of reports and transactions process.

i'll  appreciate any  suggestions,
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selection of WCF service and its binding is one of the considerations when you are designing a solution for a project which has reports and transactions process. WCF service with net.tcp binding is good if you are using inside intranet because it is fast.

You should think about other aspects also.

1. What is mechanism to display a report?
2. What is the volume of data on which reports is generated?
3. What is the hardware configuration of you database server?
4. How many concurrent no of user of this service?
5. In fact design of database a major consideration.